# Migration Assistant Reports failed files, Prompts repair errors: No Documents transferred, High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, migration-assistant

I have a 2017 Macbook Pro and a 2018 Macbook Pro. The target machine has a bigger SSD than the source, so I know it's not a space issue.

I ran Migration Assistant on both machines and the process completely relatively quickly. After it completed I received about 2 dozen files that could not be transferred. The machine than boots into macOS and I start receiving repeated authorizations requests to repair files.

I also receive notice that the keychain needs to be replaced with default.

Should I attempt to boot the source into target disk mode and transfer via thunderbolt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your Migration didn't work, even though you didn't get error messages saying so at the time.

I always use either Target Mode or an external disk when I use Migration Assistant. I also don't do the Migration until I've gotten the new computer completely up-to-date, etc. I create an extra "Admin" or other dummy account which I delete later.

I would reset the 2018 MBP, create a dummy account, do all the updates, and then when the system was running perfectly, *then* I'd start the Migration Assistant using the 2017 MBP in Target mode.

The other thing I do, because it didn't work correctly once when I did it a different way..... After selecting the source disk, MA will scan the source and identify the files, accounts, apps, etc. that need to be transferred. Since I was transferring *everything*, I didn't wait for it to calculate the sizes of all these different things, and just said "Go" or "Next" or whatever to get it started. That didn't work. So, now, I always wait for the scan of the source disk to complete. I wait to see the size of the Users folder, the size of the Apps folder, etc. before I start the Migration.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Zonker.In.Geneva, will give it a shot this morning.

Answer (score 4):

Finally...got it working.

TLDR; I put the destination machine in target-disk mode, connected it with USB-C 3.1 Male-to-Male cable and used Carbon Copy Cloner to create a new sparsebundle on the root of the drive, than ran migration assistant after mounting it while running a dummy account.

It is worth noting I wanted to do a few things:

1. Copy my machine as completely as possible (IE all my bash-profiles (I am a developer), and installed frameworks)
2. Have access to the source machine during the day for work! I don't think this is too much to ask in 2018 for a transfer of 500Gb to run over a LAN or USB-C 3.1 with all modern equipment)

There are **A LOT** of *worthless* "Migration Assistant" explanations out there. So I figured I'd post a few details of what I learned this week. This is *my experience* it may/**probably won't** work for everyone else. Plus I had the advantage of migrating **500Gb** to **1TB** which in the end was my saving grace.

Paths I tried:

1. **Open Migration Assistant on both machines both connected to the *same* router (late model Linksys AC9000) network over CAT5 cables**

**Result:** Migration assistant runs, and transfers to new machine in 2-3 hours. However (same as initial question lots of "Unable to transfer file" errors, when logging in, no Docs, Applications in directories, etc., keychain warning). **FAIL**

2. **Run Time Machine backup from source machine to external NAS (both connected over CAT5 to same Linksys AC9000 router). NAS is 12TB Symbology**

**Result:** Time Machine taking *forever* after 3-4 days I attempt to use `lowpri_throttle_enabled` [hack](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/5vb66w/speed_up_your_time_machine_backups_tremendously/), backups run faster, but keeps looping on "Backing Up" (Both ***Migration Assistant*** and ***Time Machine*** have USELESS "progress indication" **FAIL** - Gave up after backing up for 2-days

3. ***Go to Apple Store, and as employee: "What does Apple use to migrate machines when customers ask it to be done for them?" Answer: "USB-C, it costs $99, and there is no timeframe, you leave us both computers and we call you when it's done."***

**Buy generic Microcenter Inland brand "Super Speed USB 3.1 10 Gbps" USB-C Male to USB-C Male (Apple Store DOES NOT STOCK a USB-C 3.1 Male-to-Male cable as of this posting)**

**Connect machines with cable, and put source in 'Target Disk Mode' (Hold "T" key while booting), open 'Migration Assistant' on destination machine.**

**Result:** Migration Assistant relatively quickly manages to collect source-information calculations (User Account, Application, Network Settings, etc. and sizes for each - though this does not seem to have much practical effect it takes A LONG TIME) Start migration, Migration assistant shows "Starting Up" for 3-hours, no change, or estimation or copy-speed indication. **FAIL**

4. **Download [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/), I was suspicious of 3rd party back-up tools being capable of working appropriately with Apple's convoluted back-up scheme and sparse-bundle file format, but CCC 5 is definitely an *excellent tool*, so shameless plug to them! There is also a free-trial so you don't have to pay to use it full-featured for 30-days, but you should buy a license and save yourself the brain-damage of dealing with Time Machine.**

**Result:** Create new backup on NAS (Same Symbology 12TB NAS as before), since my Time Machine backup indefinitely never finished after 4-days. *Wait* (not as long as Time Machine) but overnight 4-5 hours *over LAN CAT6* now. Open Migration Assistant on target machine, attach network drive, see my backup, and wait.

Migration assistant says: "Loading Backup" for 12-14 hours, I cannot click "Continue" as it is deactivated. I can see network traffic moving from the NAS to the computer and so on, but after 15 hours I give up. **FAIL**

5. **Put destination machine into target disk mode, and connect with USB-C 3.1 Male-to-Male cable to source. Format target drive, remember it has 1TB of space, and backup is only ~500Gb. Open Carbon Copy Cloner, and create new back-up on root of attached target-disk drive. This takes about 2-hours (relatively fast compared to other attempts). Attempt to boot into recovery (Discover machine just hangs at the Apple *Spinning Globe* screen, until I place backup sparsebundle inside of a directory on the root of the drive, I just call it `backup/macbook-pro-2017.sparsebundle`**

**Result**: I than reinstall MacOS, and create a dummy account (as suggested by @Zonker.in.Geneva) and than boot, run updates, verify that I still have my `.sparsebundle` archive, than I "mount it" (Double click it in Finder), and than open Migration Assistant.

Now I see `Macbook-Pro-2017` as a source, I select it, and it *very quickly* manages to do the size calculations. I start the migration once they complete, it's worth noting that as a developer I have A LOT of tiny files (*it calculated 3.5 million in the sparsebundle*),

Migration takes ~12 hours. Again the time/progress indicators are WORTHLESS. Sometimes it says reading 130mb/s, sometimes nothing. Sometimes 3 days to finish, sometimes 3 hours. It's completely worthless.

Finally, I reboot the machine and it says "Migration Complete" and magically, I am able to login to my account as if I was on the original machine, and it appears so far that everything is as expected.

The big caveat here is that I had a 1TB machine as a destination for ~500Gb worth of files, and after migration I only have about 50Gb of space left before I delete the sparsebundle. **SUCCESS**, now if I could only get the last week of time I spent messing around with this back. *Thanks for the productivity bump Apple.*

Comment: Does this change at all with Catalina? I just tried to migrate using a USB-C cable and that failed with a vague error message. Also, I've read that TimeMachine connected over to a NAS can have issues. Did you try TimeMachine connected via USB?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when migrating from even my old mid-2014 to a 2023. It was stuck on "looking for documents and apps to transfer", even though I was using a CCC backup USB-C to USB-C.

I ended up following [these](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc6/i-want-clone-my-entire-hard-drive-new-hard-drive-or-new-machine) instructions, which required basically to turn on CCC Snapshot, and to do a verification post-flight.

Upon trying it again, it quickly moved from the stuck "looking for stuff to transfer" page to the actual transferring part, complete with a proper status bar.

Hope that helps.